# CSS - text alignment and forcing overflow to the left?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Jakobud/VfVnN/7/

I want the `.title` div to be left-aligned with the `.text` div. But if the `.title` div is wider than the .`text` div then I want the overflow to go to the left. I don't want it to go to the right or wrap to another line.

How can I accomplish this with pure CSS.

Comment: it is very unclear to me what you are asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VfVnN/5/ ?

*Updated:* You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VfVnN/6/

Gave the header a `min-width` equal to the text and because of the `float: right`, it will expand to the left (given theres room for that in your design)

Comment: Aha that is exactly what I wanted. I knew there was a way. Thanks!